# no abre las imágenes de la base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, pdo

Las imágenes no se muestran, los archivos en la carpeta fuente están bien, y no marca ningún tipo de error en la pantalla, todo lo demás se muestra excepto la imagen, este es el código del capítulo.php, la parte dentro del foreach es el que no muestra la imagen. No pongo la conexión, porque si se conecta con el resto de funciones

```
<?php 
   $hoja = new Mangas();
   $hojas = $hoja->hojas($_GET['id']);

   !$_GET ? header('location: capitulo.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'&pagina=1') : '';
   $nFilas = $hoja->numeroFilas();  //cuenta las paginas existentes
   $x = $_GET['pagina']-1; //Estable el rango
   $pagina = $hoja->getLink($x,$_GET['id']); //Proporciona el numero de paginas del manga

?>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12 margen">
           
           <div class="cover" align="center">
               <h1><?php echo $hojas['numeroCap']; ?></h1>
               <?php foreach ($pagina as $pagina): ?>
               <img src="img/capitulos/<?php echo $pagina['hoja']; ?>" class="img-responsive"><!--Expulsa eel el link con respecto a la pagina-->
               <?php endforeach ?>
               
           </div>
           <div align="center">
               <span class="btn btn-info <?php echo $_GET['pagina']<=1 ? 'disabled' : '' ?>"><a href="capitulo.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']-1; ?>">Prev</a></span>
               <span class="btn btn-info <?php echo $_GET['pagina']>=$nFilas ? 'disabled' : '' ?>"><a href="capitulo.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>&pagina=<?php echo $_GET['pagina']+1; ?>">Next</a></span>
           </div>
               
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

la public function hoja es la sentencia que se conecta con la base de datos y debe traer las imágenes

```
<?php 
include_once 'conexion.php';
   class Mangas extends Conexion {
       public function Mangas(){
           parent::__construct();
       }
       public function mangaUsuario(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga ORDER BY manga.id ASC";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function directorio($empieza,$tamanoPaginas){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga ORDER BY manga.id ASC LIMIT $empieza,$tamanoPaginas";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function numeroMangas(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->rowCount();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function mangaUsuarios($id){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga WHERE id = '$id'";
           $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function listaCap(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulosmanga ORDER BY capitulosmanga.id DESC LIMIT 10";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function sideBarList(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM manga ORDER BY manga.id DESC LIMIT 5";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       
       public function subirPortada($manga,$sinopsis,$sinopsisCorta,$imagen,$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4,$a5,$a6){
           if($imagen['imagen']['name']<=5000000) {
               if ($imagen['imagen']['type']=="image/jpeg" || $imagen['imagen']['type']=="image/png" || $imagen['imagen']['type']=="image/gif") {
               
                   //ruta imagen
                   $carpeta_destino = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/manga/img/portadas/";
                   //mover imagen del directorio temporal a directorio escogido
                   move_uploaded_file($imagen['imagen']['tmp_name'], $carpeta_destino.$imagen['imagen']['name']);
               }
           }
           $sql = "INSERT INTO manga(nombre, portada,sinopsis,sinopsisCorta,A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6) VALUES (:nombre, :portada,:sinopsis,:sinopsisCorta,:A1,:A2,:A3,:A4,:A5,:A6)";
           $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
           $statement->execute(array(':nombre' => $manga, ':portada' => $imagen['imagen']['name'],':sinopsis' => $sinopsis,':sinopsisCorta' => $sinopsisCorta,':A1' => $a1,':A2' => $a2,':A3' => $a3,':A4' => $a4,':A5' => $a5,':A6' => $a6));
           header('location: ../_admin/panel.php');
       }
       public function subirHojas($numeroCap,$numeroVol,$hojas,$mangaRel){//metodo con parametros del formulario
           
           if(isset($hojas["file"])){//condicional para saber si hay imagenes
               for ($i=0; $i <count($hojas['file']['name']) ; $i++) { //bucle para recorrer todas imagenes
                   $file = $hojas['file']; //array de todas la imagenes
                   $nombre = $file['name'][$i]; // nombre de la imagen
                   $tipo = $file['type'][$i]; // tipo de imagen
                   $size = $file['size'][$i]; //tamaño de la imagen
                   $ruta_temp = $file['tmp_name'][$i]; //ruta tamporales de la imagen
                   $carpeta = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/manga/img/capitulos/"; //ruta personalizada
                   if ($tipo != 'image/jpeg' && $tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/png' && $tipo != 'image/png') {
                       echo $reporte .= "<p>Error: ".$nombre." no es una iamgen.</p>";//condicional para validar el tipo deimagen
                   }else if($size > 5000000){
                       echo $reporte .= "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede el maximo permitido.</p>";//condicional para validadr el tamaño deimagen
                   }else{
                       $src = $carpeta.$nombre;
                       move_uploaded_file($ruta_temp, $src);//mandamos la imagen al directorio propuesto
                       
                   }
                   $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulos(hoja, pagina, hojaRel) VALUES (:hoja, :pagina, :hojaRel)";//consulta para la insersion de registro a la base de datos
                   $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
                   $page = $i +1;
                   $statement->execute(array(':hoja' => $nombre,':pagina' => $page, ':hojaRel' => $mangaRel));                 
               }
               $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulosmanga(numeroCap, numeroVol, mangaRel) VALUES (:numeroCap, :numeroVol, :mangaRel)";//consulta para la insersion de registro a la base de datos
                   $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
                   $statement->execute(array(':numeroCap' => $numeroCap, ':numeroVol' => $numeroVol, ':mangaRel' => $mangaRel));
               echo "<p>Sus imagenes se subieron exitosamente.</p>";//respues devuelta por aJAX
           }
       }
       public function URLCapitulo($id){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulosmanga WHERE capitulosmanga.mangaRel = '$id' ORDER BY capitulosmanga.numeroCap DESC";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function hojas($id){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos,capitulosmanga WHERE capitulos.hojaRel='$id' AND capitulosmanga.id = '$id'";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
           $statement->closeCursor();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function getLink($x,$id){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos,capitulosmanga WHERE capitulos.hojaRel='$id' AND capitulosmanga.id = '$id' LIMIT $x,1";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function numeroFilas(){
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos";
           $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
           $statement->execute(array());
           $resultado = $statement->rowCount();
           return $resultado;
       }
       public function eliminarManga($id){
           $this->base->query("DELETE FROM manga WHERE id='$id'");
           header('location: ../_admin/panel.php');
       }
   }
   
   
?>
```

Tengo que omitir la parte del código html, el meta, js y otros.el error deberia estar entre esos dos

Comment: ademas,parece que no conecta con las consultas porque tmp imprime el h1 con el nombre del capitulo

Comment: ¿Ves algún error en los logs?

Comment: En el `foreach`, no pongas el nombre de la variable  alias (`as`)  igual que el array, intenta algo así: `<?php foreach ($pagina as $row): ?> <img src="img/capitulos/<?php echo $row['hoja']; ?>" class="img-responsive"><!--Expulsa eel el link con respecto a la pagina-->
               <?php endforeach ?>` NÓTESE que aquí el alias se llamará `$row`  y deberás usar `$row['hoja']` dentro del bucle ... Si no te funciona, depura tu código, por ejemplo, pon un `var_dump($pagina);`  revisa los valores y verifica si construirían un src válido. Eso es parte del ABC de la depuración de código...

Comment: el sitema de login es muy basico, asi que no esta dando errores ,pero si lo voy cambiar